# Problema al utilizar $this- Error: Using $this when not in object- Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

Actualmente estoy utilizando el **framework yii2**, este posee un generador de código llamado gii. Al utilizar el gii para generar el modelo, vista y controlador no hay problema, me crea los 3 sin problema, el verdadero problema es cuando quiero ver el resultado en el servidor local. El error que me arroja es este:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Using $this when not in object context in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\views\Equipo\index.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\basic\views\Equipo\index.php on line 10

Esta es la accion de mi controlador (SE LLAMA "EquipoController"):

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $searchModel = new EquipoSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
            return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

Esta es mi vista y donde me genera el error:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\EquipoSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

 $this->title = 'Inventario'; //Esta es la linea 10
 $this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
 ?>
```

Porfavor necesito ayuda para saber porque se produce el error y como solucionarlo, gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pareces que estas intentando de abrir la vista directamente, usando un link como `http://localhost/app/views/equipo/index.php`.
*Esta no es la manera de acceder a la pagina, todo tienes que pasar para el controller.*

Ademas, tu aplicación es accesible desde un único punto que es esto `http://localhost/app/web/index.php`

Desde aquì tienes que indicar *cual controller y action usar*, asì que tu link para acceder a la action index de EquipoController tiene que ser esto: `http://localhost/app/web/index.php?r=equipo/index`

Comment: Fabrizio recuerda leer el [tour] para aprender más de este sitio. Un saludo

Comment: Problema resuelto, muchas gracias :)